# Hibernate entity query to Set<>

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, set

My goal is to write the shortest query to get current Test by User id
My UserEntity.class part:

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "result", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_id"))
private Set<Test> tests;
```

Here is the example how can i get all tests for him (my UserDAO.class):

> ```
> public List<Test> getAvailableTestsById(long id){
>     Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u.tests FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id");
>     query.setParameter("id", id);
>     return (List<Test>)query.getResultList();
> }
> ```
>
> Now i would like to get one (for example by id) test for user. How can i do that in best way? I can write long sql query with many joins but i feel that this is not an appropriate solution. Can i use my Set in UserEntity.class to find test which i need (by id)?

Comment: If you have the ID of the test, why don't you just use em.find(Test.class, id)? Why would you need a long query with many joins to do that?

Comment: @JBNizet, how could i check is this test available for current user or not then?

Comment: You don't even need to load it to do that: `user.getTests().stream().anyMatch(test -> test.getId().equals(testId))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `get` the user or `load` it if you are sure that the user exists, and then get the `Test`s of that user:

```
User user =  session.load(User.class, userId);
```

or

```
User user =  (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
```